# How can I swap selected data in 2 rows based on criteria

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am new to Python.

Suppose I have DataFrame, and want to switch selected data of all rows with similar id.

For example:

```
|  id  | Gender |  Name   |   Hobby    |   Food    |
+------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+
| 1111 | Male   | Robert  | Swim       | Ice-cream |
| 1112 | Female | Natasha | Football   | Pizza     |
| 1111 | Female | Misa    | Volleyball | Pasta     |
| 1112 | Male   | Rick    | Sleep      | Hamburger |
| 1113 | Male   | Rondo   | Read       | Rice      |
+------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+
```

Expected output:

```
+------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+
|  id  | Gender |  Name   |   Hobby    |   Food    |
+------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+
| 1111 | Male   | Robert  | Volleyball | Pasta     |
| 1112 | Female | Natasha | Sleep      | Hamburger |
| 1111 | Female | Misa    | Swim       | Ice-cream |
| 1112 | Male   | Rick    | Football   | Pizza     |
| 1113 | Male   | Rondo   | Read       | Rice      |
+------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+
```

So what I want to do is to switch data (In this example only Hobby and Food) between people with same id, but  name and gender remain the same.

So basicly, on first row, id 1111, Gender is Male, Name is Robert - Hobby will be Volleyball and Food will be Pasta. 
On second row, id 1111, Gender is female name is Misa - hobby will be swim and food will be ice-cream. And do the same for the id 1112 as well. 
I do not have any idea at the moment, except for writing some loop and then use empty DataFramme to append and switch.
Thank you all!!

Comment: Can you please provide an expected output.

Comment: It seems like what you need is to sort data by `id`? Am I correct?

Comment: I just posed expected output, thank you

Comment: Is it possible to have more then two rows with the same ID? If so, how the third row will be handle?

Comment: Hi, I do not understand what you meant. If you mean the fifth row, then since there is no matching id, it will not be switched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of swapping other columns, I choose to swap `Name` and `Gender`:

```
def swap(x):
    x[['Gender','Name']] = x[['Gender','Name']].values[::-1]
    return x

df.groupby('id').apply(swap)
```

Output:

```
     id  Gender     Name       Hobby       Food
0  1111  Female     Misa        Swim   Icecream
1  1112    Male     Rick    Football      Pizza
2  1111    Male   Robert  Volleyball      Pasta
3  1112  Female  Natasha       Sleep  Hamburger
4  1113    Male    Rondo        Read       Rice
```

Or if you insist on the correct order, then swap the other columns:

```
def swap2(x):
    x[['Hobby','Food']] = x[['Hobby','Food']].values[::-1]

    return x

print(df.groupby('id').apply(swap2))
```

Output:

```
     id  Gender     Name       Hobby       Food
0  1111    Male   Robert  Volleyball      Pasta
1  1112  Female  Natasha       Sleep  Hamburger
2  1111  Female     Misa        Swim   Icecream
3  1112    Male     Rick    Football      Pizza
4  1113    Male    Rondo        Read       Rice
```

Comment: I didn't check but it's looks amazing. I don't see you handle checking that the Name and\or Gender are different between swapping rows.

Comment: Hi, in this example you can do that, but most of the time not, I should have write a more difficult example. For example, if id 1111 Robert is in row 0, and id 1111 Misa is in row 99, I need to find its location first, before switching

Comment: As long as you have *at most* 2 rows per id, it works.

Comment: I see, thank you, I ll try it and mark my question as resolved